# Is it possible to add an "ignore" option and block any user from commenting on our answers?

Tags: feature-request, comments, users

When a user is commenting unnecessarily on our answers, how about if we can block that user from posting those comments.

Comment: You can't. Though if the comment is not constructive or adds nothing and doesn't ask for precision or what so ever, you can flag it. (with the little flag that appears when you hover a comment)

Comment: @ Hugo Dozois : but can we not suggest stack exchange website owners to add this as an option?

Comment: You just did, Sweet72.

Comment: Do you have a link to some specific question/answer?

Comment: I have doubt about "unnecessarily" here... Example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a user is posting comments that are actually inappropriate, unconstructive, abusive, offtopic, or in any other way a violation of the rules of the site, you can flag them and they will be deleted.  If they continue to repeat this behavior a moderator will take further action to prevent them from continuing.

If the comments are not a violation of any rules and you simply don't like them then you shouldn't be able to block them from being posted.  The primary reason that that people would have a problem with comments that are truly constructive, not inappropriate, on topic, etc. would be because they are pointing out valid flaws in an answer, and those are exactly the comments that shouldn't be deleted under a post, not the ones that a poster should be able to delete or prevent.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that such feature is needed. The steps I would take:

1. Ignore the first time.
2. If the user keeps doing it, reply to him and ask to stop, nicely.
3. If the user is still posting comments you think are not relevant or constructive just flag them.

Those are just comments, really no need to block users just for such thing.

Comment: "flag the comment" can be done at each of those steps.

Answer (score 3):

What would this block accomplish?  Blocking YOU from seeing his replies?  Blocking HIM from replying?  The former is unnecessary, the latter would make everyone a Mod.  I don't think this is necessary (or practical) at all.  As stated by several people, you can (and should) flag any comments that are extraneous or off-topic.  This will help clean up the Q&A.  Additionally, you can hit him with an @Username and remind him to stay on-topic.